# Html input hide text on select and show if leave it empty

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a form there is a problem I have set the value of text box

```
<input type="text" value="First name" id="TbName">
<input type="text" value="Email" id="TbEmail">
<input type="text" value="School" id="TbSchool">
```

I want to hide the value if user selects that box for filling text and if he/she doesn't enter anything in the box and selects another box than the value of text box will again show the default value.
I have lots of forms and many fields so it is not possible to write seperate code for each one, is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name">
```

use `placeholder` to have the value

Comment: Good, But Adding a fact. The placeholder attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. So wont work in IE 6-9

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using **[$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)**:

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="First name" data-default="First name" id="TbName">
<input type="text" value="Email" data-default="Email" id="TbEmail">
<input type="text" value="School" data-default="School" id="TbSchool">
```

### JQuery:

```
$('input:text').each(function(){
    $.data(this, 'default', this.value);
}).focus(function(){
    if ($.data(this, 'default') == this.value) {
        this.value = '';
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = $.data(this, 'default');
    }
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/JGUE2/)**